# Tracking expenses/receipts - integrating a List with Windows and iPhone users

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-form, library, onedrive-for-business

I'm volunteering to help a non-profit set up their SharePoint Online site.

One of the requirements is that they need a way for staff/volunteers to upload receipts for any purchases they've made. These then need to be accessed by an accounts person on a Windows computer for uploading to MYOB.

Initially I designed a List for this purpose. This works well - volunteers can install the Lists app on their iPhones and complete a short form and attach the receipt. This appears fine on SPO, but the problem I'm having is that I can't seem to find a way for the accounts person to access the receipts on their Windows based computer running MYOB.

Initially I thought I could just sync the list to OneDrive, or use the Map Network Drive option in Windows to map to the list and view/access the images, but this doesn't seem possible. I then tried adding a 'Download' calculated column and using json to allow the accounts person to click on a download link to download the image, but this is clunky as it requires them to download each receipt one by one. (There's lots of receipts)

So, I then created a Library instead with essentially the same columns the List had. But of course, volunteers can't access this using the Lists app on their iPhones, so we tried installing the SharePoint app instead. But this just doesn't seem to work properly - that is, there's no easy way to access the library to add/upload a new file (i.e. an image file with the metadata needed). It works sometimes and not other times, and the app just seems clunky and buggy, with volunteers often having to sign out and back in for it to work properly.

In summary:

- **with a List:** volunteers/staff have no problem with the Lists app to upload receipts to a List - it works intuitively for them - but the accounts person can't seem to access the receipts in Windows
- **with a Library:** the accounts person can access receipts via OneDrive in Windows just fine, but volunteers/staff are having issues using the SharePoint app to upload receipts
- Either way, someone isn't happy, but I need this to be functional for all parties

**Is there a way to set up a list so that the image files attached to
one of the columns are easily accessible in Windows?**

If not, is there an easier way for staff/volunteers to upload images from an iPhone to a SharePoint Library and complete the metadata (instead of having to use the SharePoint app)?